# hasMany on Cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I want to make a transaction with 1 transaction many products. but I have a problem only the last index entered on the product. is there a solution?[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DWWS.png)

[Model Table[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqbVO.png)

Comment: First, please copy your code here (with correct formatting) instead of using links to images of your code. Many people won't follow your links (they could be nefarious), and they make it impossible for people to copy-any-paste your code to test for themselves (which hinders finding the problem). Second, you've shown the setup for the wrong table, we would need to see the initialization for the Purchasing table to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you are using an array on select query. to fetch all the records.
For eg,

```
$posts = $this->Employees->find("all")
        ->contain(["employeePosts" => function($q){
        return $q->select(["id", "employee_id", "post_title"]);
         }])
        ->toList();
 echo print_r("posts");
```

here employee_id is a foreign key. and employeePosts is a key I created in EmployeesTable in hasMany()

```
$this->hasMany("employeeposts")->setClassName("Posts")
```